# Ocorrendo erro ao setar valores um loop "React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop"

Tags: javascript, react, for, expo

Bom, tenho um `useEffect` que busca meus dados de uma API e depois faço um set dos valores para um `useState`, porém está entrando em loop infinito e não consigo pegar os meus valores na outra variável que criei.

```
export default function ForecastDashboard() {
    const [codCity, setCodCity] = useState(4209102);

    const [dataCity, setDataCity] = useState([]);
    const [dataClimate, setDataClimate] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            
            const getAllDataClimate = async () => {
                const { data } = await apiClima.get(`/${codCity}`);
                const cities =  data[codCity];
                setDataCity(cities);     
            };

            getAllDataClimate();

        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }       
    }, []);

    

    for(const i in dataCity){
        const { manha, tarde, noite } = dataCity[i];
        console.log(manha, tarde, noite)
        //setDataClimate([ manha, tarde, noite ]);
    }

    return (
        <View style={ForecastDashboardCSS.container}>
            {dataClimate.map(i => (
                <View style={ForecastDashboardCSS.card}>
                    <Text>{i}</Text>
                </View>
            ))}
        </View>
    );
}
```

[image]

Dados que estou recebendo das variáveis de `manha`, `tarde` e `noite`.

Estou meio perdido porque não sei exatamente o que tenho que fazer para contornar isso. Estava buscando algumas soluções, porém não obtive sucesso. Meu erro ocorre se colocar o `setDataClimate` dentro do `for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O fato de entrar em loop infinito se deve ao fato de você chamar o `setDataClimate` no laço `for` dentro do corpo da função, **você não deve fazer isto!**. [A própria documentação do React explica:](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

> Mutações, assinaturas, temporizadores, logs e outros side effects **não são permitidos dentro do corpo principal de um componente funcional** (React se refere a isso como render phase). Usá-los levará a erros confusos e inconsistências na UI.

Um desses erros é loop infinito. O fato de você renderizar um componente baseado em uma variável de estado (`dataClimate`) e fazer um `setState` dessa variável imediatemente dentro do corpo da função (`setDataClimate`), pode ser o motivo desse erro.

E mais:

> Em vez disso, use `useEffect`. A função passada para useEffect será executada depois que a renderização estiver disponível na tela. Pense em efeitos como um rota de fuga do mundo puramente funcional do React para o mundo imperativo.

Então para resolver seu caso, vamos usar um hook de efeito para a propriedade `dataCity`.

Eu fiz um *mock* do seu código para recriar seu problema. Abaixo o seu código *mockado* **estruturado para simular seu erro**:

```js
function App() {
  const mock = { '4209102': [{ cidade: 'cidade1', manha: 'ceu claro', tarde: 'chuvoso', noite: 'nublado' }, { cidade: 'cidade2', manha: 'ceu claro', tarde: 'chuvoso', noite: 'nublado' }, { cidade: 'cidade3', manha: 'ceu claro', tarde: 'chuvoso', noite: 'nublado' }] };

  const [codCity, setCodCity] = React.useState(4209102);
  const [dataCity, setDataCity] = React.useState([]);
  const [dataClimate, setDataClimate] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const getAllDataClimate = () => {
        // const { data } = await apiClima.get(`/${codCity}`);
        const { data } = { data: mock };
        const cities = data[codCity];

        setDataCity(cities);
      };

      getAllDataClimate();

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, []);

  
  for (const i in dataCity) {
   const { manha, tarde, noite } = dataCity[i];
   console.log('LOGS: ', manha, tarde, noite);
   setDataClimate([manha, tarde, noite]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Teste</h1>
      {dataClimate.map((value, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{value}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Agora vamos adaptar o código para resolver o problema. Vamos usar o `useEffect` para a propriedade `dataCity`. Como vai ficar este hook:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    for (const i in dataCity) {
      const { manha, tarde, noite } = dataCity[i];
      console.log('LOGS: ', manha, tarde, noite);
      setDataClimate([manha, tarde, noite]);
    }
  }, [dataCity]);
```

Agora, quando `dataCity` tiver o estado alterado pelo `getAllDataClimate`, vamos trabalhar em cima desta mudança através do `useEffect` e refletir essa mudança usando `setDataClimate` para ai sim os componentes possam ser renderizados sem erro.

Código *mockado* completo e funcionando abaixo:

```js
function App() {
  const mock = { '4209102': [{ cidade: 'cidade1', manha: 'ceu claro', tarde: 'chuvoso', noite: 'nublado' }, { cidade: 'cidade2', manha: 'ceu claro', tarde: 'chuvoso', noite: 'nublado' }, { cidade: 'cidade3', manha: 'ceu claro', tarde: 'chuvoso', noite: 'nublado' }] };

  const [codCity, setCodCity] = React.useState(4209102);
  const [dataCity, setDataCity] = React.useState([]);
  const [dataClimate, setDataClimate] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const getAllDataClimate = () => {
        // const { data } = await apiClima.get(`/${codCity}`);
        const { data } = { data: mock };
        const cities = data[codCity];

        setDataCity(cities);
      };

      getAllDataClimate();

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
   for (const i in dataCity) {
    const { manha, tarde, noite } = dataCity[i];
    console.log('LOGS: ', manha, tarde, noite);
    setDataClimate([manha, tarde, noite]);
   }
  }, [dataCity]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Teste</h1>
      {dataClimate.map((value, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{value}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

O lance de passar o `dataCity` como parâmetro no `useEffect` é explicado na documentação:

> No entanto, isto pode ser excessivo em alguns casos, como o exemplo de assinatura da seção anterior. Nós não precisamos criar uma nova assinatura toda vez que atualizar, apenas se a props source for alterada.

> Para implementar isso, passe um segundo argumento para useEffect que pode ser um array de valores em que o efeito observa.

Neste caso, estamos observando `dataCity`.

---

#### Atenção

Este código utiliza o React Web apenas para exemplificar o seu problema e a solução de uma forma que possa ser testada diretamente aqui na SOpt graças ao snippet de código. Faça as devidas adaptações para que o código funcione no React Native. Substitua `div` por `View`, `p` por `Text`, ....

Comment: Testei aqui e deu certo, valeu. Não sabia que não podia coloca um bloco de código dessa forma